# Unable to solve any Euler questions. Fundamental error I cannot find

Tags: complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

Good day,

I have been trying to solve Euler based questions for a day now. And i realize I still cannot solve a single one, and am getting errors for all my questions. I feel like I am getting something fundamentally wrong. I was hoping to place my questions/equations here and see if the community can detect my error.

[image]

[image]

Comment: ah ok that solves it but i get 0.327<1.17

Comment: my sign for the angle is wrong

Comment: Mate you'll have to take a better photo cause I'm struggling to read your writing. In the first part, line 1, does the last exponential say $-j$x$2\pi$x$\frac{4}{8}$? If so, how did you get $\frac{6\pi}{8}$ in line 2 for your cos and sin?

Comment: sorry thats a times not an x

Comment: Yeah I know it's a times, I just couldn't write it in latex without having the multiplication look like this $x$. Could you take another picture?

Comment: I'll write a larger post and show you what I did and you tell me if I have put in the correct question ok.

Comment: ok. i will attach an additional image to the post

Comment: hmm looks the i cant get chat to work on my browser nvmind